# How is this type of 'patterned' grid-like background created?

Tags: javascript, css, background

can anyone tell me how this type of 'noisy', grid-like background is created? Here's theme preview:

http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/one-page/index.php

I actually have the theme, but can't figure out the piece of code that makes this happen, I use the "inspect element" function, but can't find anything, which makes me think this is not even created with css, JS maybe?

Thanks!

EDIT: OMG, a simple overlay image, I feel so dumb :) Thanks guys

Comment: hint: `background:url(images/grid.png)`;

Comment: check `.video-overlay` div. it has also an inliner style `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.55);`

Comment: @SalemOuerdani ... a solid colour does not produce a grid!

Comment: yes i mean .video-overlay content (wich has images/grid.png) + the background-color

Answer (score 0):

It's an overlay image.

In the debug tools from chrome go to resources -> images -> `grid.png`. It's a 6 x 6 image.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/YD1uvthZwg4/860x660);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
  
}

.overlay{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://canvashtml-cdn.semicolonweb.com/images/grid.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="overlay" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.55);"></div>
</div>
```